# Accessing Parent Array Names

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have got my App returning this array: http://pastebin.com/3VKcjLMT

I'm trying to list the data on my laravel view as:

```
FAB0003 - Accessory Stand Short Section
-- MAC0010
-- CUT0010

FAB0004 - Accessory Stand Long Section
-- MAC0011
-- RAW0010
```

but I can't for the life of me figure out how to access the pieces of information beginning with FAB! My current view code is this:

```
@foreach ($product->fabrications as $items)                                      
@foreach ($items as $item)
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>{{ $item->part_number }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

I would be so grateful if you could help out a PHP noob who has wasted hours on this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with -

```
@foreach ($product->fabrications as $key => $items)
```

`$key` will be the parent key.

> Note : It should be a array key.

Comment: Oh my sweet lord thank you. It sucks being a noob because you never know the correct terms to use to search for your answer and it's usually something so simple. Guess I just have to keep reading...